# Откат навыка в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать перезарядку/кулдаун навыка в юнити ?
Мне необходимо сделать перезарядку "рывка" в юнити, думал сделать с помощью куротины, но не получилось. Подкиньте идей, реализация через куротину:
public class PlayrJerk : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] int jerkImpuls;
public static int afterJerkImpuls;
[SerializeField] int jerkAmmount;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

```
    void Start()
    {
        jerkAmmount = 1;
        jerkImpuls = 15;
        afterJerkImpuls = 4;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Jerk();
    }

    void Jerk()
    {
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && jerkAmmount == 1)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.right * jerkImpuls;
            jerkAmmount--;
            Reload();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            PlayerJump.extraJump++;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.left * afterJerkImpuls;
        }

        IEnumerator Reload()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            jerkAmmount = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Собственно корутиной и делается %)

Comment: Почему-то не получается, подскажите в чем ошибка, пожалуйста. Я прикрепил код ниже.

Comment: Код необходимо располагать непосредственно в вопросе. Отредактируйте его и добавьте, код, описав **конкретную** проблему, что конкретно с ним не так. А ответ надо удалить

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали,надеюсь получить ответ.